# What for azure-mgmt-redis maven dependency is used?

Tags: azure, redis

I'm trying to use azure sdk for redis using springboot in order to connect to redis from Java application. I have come across two dependencies in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/rediscache?view=azure-java-stable) . What for **azure-mgmt-redis** dependency is used ?

Can any one please help me out regarding the same ?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
    <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-mgmt-redis</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`azure-mgmt-redis` is used for manage Azure redis resources.For instance, you can use it to create/delete Azure Redis instances, import data, or update your Azure Redis instances configs.

This SDK is based on [Azure management REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/redis/redis).

`Jedis` is used for calling Azure Redis services such as getting/setting key/values.